# How to set the color of a text object dynamically in crystal reports?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, reporting

I'm designing a report using Crystal reports for Visual Studio 2010.
In my report I have a details section and each record of details must have a specific color.
I've saved each row's color RGB code in the database and I need to set it for its record.

How can I do it in Crystal Reports? I've designed the same report using Microsoft Reporting Service and everything is working fine there, but I need to implement this in Crystal Reports too.

Please Help me.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fields you can write your own function to set their font color - look at field properties, font tab, color property. You need to use RGB function probably, although simple 32bit RGB values should work either.

For text objects this is directly not possible, but you can always create formulas, returning only constant text and you can play with font color of these formula fields too.

Comment: Would you please send me an example?

Comment: You mean example of function or what?

Comment: RGB({redfieldvalue}, {greenfieldvalue}, {bluefieldvalue})